# I would like to setup ETH purchase by Visa/Pay-Pal on my webpage. How to do it?

Tags: payments

As in title. The only option that I know is going to exchange websites and purchasing from those websites. Would there be a way to simply setup the payment option directly from my web-page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exchanges offer customizable widgets that can be integrated on your webpage. Hence users does not need to go to exchange but can use it directly to purchase from your website.

[Changelly](https://changelly.com/) is one such exchange.